# Issues with ifstream and overloading operator

Tags: c++, ifstream

So I'm having issues reading from a file with an overloaded input operator ">>"

This is my code for int main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testHeader.h"
#include <vector>
#include "testHeader2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("inputfile.txt");
    vector<testHeader2> c;
    c.resize(5);
    inFile >> c[0];
    cout << c[0];
    cout << endl;
    c[0].setHeader2("AAAA", 120, 140, 150, 160, 170, 10000);
    cout << c[0];
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my header file test:

```
#ifndef TESTHEADER2_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTHEADER2_H_INCLUDED
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "testHeader2.h"
class testHeader2
{
    private:
        std::string str;
        double d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6;
    public:
        void setHeader2(std::string mystr, double g, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f)
        {
            str = mystr;
            d1 = g;
            d2 = b;
            d3 = c;
            d4 = d;
            d5 = e;
            d6 = f;

        }
        friend std::ifstream& operator>> (std::ifstream& input, testHeader2& a)
        {
        input >> a.str
        >> a.d1
        >> a.d2
        >> a.d3
        >> a.d4
        >> a.d5
        >> a.d6;
        return input;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output, const testHeader2 &a)
        {
        output << a.str << std::right << std::setprecision(2)
        << a.d1 << a.d2 <<
        a.d3 << a.d4 <<
        a.d5 << a.d6;
        return output;
        }

};

#endif // TESTHEADER2_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is a line from the .txt

```
AAAA 120 140 150 160 170 10000
```

My output overload seems to work, tested with the setHeader2 function.

What am I doing wrong? It seems to go off the rails after the first string, as it thereafter puts random values into the double values. It successfully reads the string, and then fails to read the doubles. Can anyone explain what's going wrong here? Are the spaces somehow messing things up? They never have in the past...

The output is:
AAAA1.2e+0021.4e+0021.5e+0021.6e+0021.7e+0021e+004
AAAA1.2e+0021.4e+0021.5e+0021.6e+0021.7e+0021e+004

Any ideas?

Comment: Those "random values" should be included in your question verbatim, as I suspect they're anything-but. I suspect the difference between your first construction of 3+digit doubles and your second of single-digits plays a significant role in the data you are seeing (and we're not, because you didn't post it). Your example that "works" should be using `c[0].setHeader2("AAAA", 120, 140, 150, 160, 170, 10000);` to compare apples to apples.

Comment: AAAA1.2e+0021.4e+0021.5e+0021.6e+0021.7e+0021e+004
aaaa1.2e+0022.3e+0023.5e+0024.6e+0025.7e+0026.7e+002 


You were right that changing the inputs in setHeader2 changed the outputs. Why am I getting these outputs though? Why won't it read past the first string properly?

For reference, the new inputs were "aaaa, 123,234,345,456,567,667" respectively. I will alter the main post if you think that would be best.

Also how do I do a linebreak in this format? Every time I hit enter it posts my comment and shift+enter makes a linebreak here but doesn't make one in the actual comment...